# Load SVG files in Angular-Cli

Tags: webpack, angular-cli

We're using Angular CLI for our Angular 2 project. The project uses one large SVG that's stored in node_modules folder and that svg needs to be downloaded on runtime when needed.

If we add this into the angular-cli.json

```
"addons": [
    "../node_modules/my_module/**/*.svg"
],
```

And then `require(../node_modules/my_module/icons.svg);` in one of our components the svg file gets hashed and works as expected.

The problem with this solution is that the tests fails, karma outputs:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/my_module/icons.svg
Module parse failed: path-to-svg/node_modules/my_module/icons.svg Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| <svg>
|     <defs>
```

The question is what is the correct way for including this file in the bundler?

**Karma.conf.js:**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '../',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'angular-cli'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
      require('karma-remap-istanbul'),
      require('angular-cli/plugins/karma')
    ],
    files: [
      { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false }
    ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/test.ts': ['angular-cli']
    },
    remapIstanbulReporter: {
      reports: {
        html: 'coverage',
        lcovonly: './coverage/coverage.lcov'
      }
    },
    angularCli: {
      config: './angular-cli.json',
      environment: 'dev'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'karma-remap-istanbul'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Comment: share your karma config

Comment: what did you come up with finally?